# Bad Request : 400, when generating bearer token for OAuth2.0

Tags: api, testing, jmeter

I have setup an api in jmeter which will generate the bearer token for OAuth 2.0. When checking the request body in view result tree listener, seems like jmeter is not parsing the -Client Secret key.

request making

[image]

View Result tree - Request body

[image]

Response - 400

[image]

Comment: Is it really working on the browser? Could you please attach the screen shot or some other reference? because I guess you are missing something in the request parameter.

Comment: I am able to generate the token for the same on Postman.

Comment: @JyotiPrakashMallick here you go -   https://drive.google.com/file/d/16wlsBtuwt27qg4CN-Cx1AbiN8BGNmoUW/view?usp=sharing, https://drive.google.com/file/d/1T8CfBGdfUFWISq9aMaoW66uYULDq6WMA/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below,

Tried it on postman, (working fine)

[image]

Now from JMeter, (working fine)

[image]

[image]

[image]

I guess you missed the checkboxes (`URL Encode?`) in the request parameters in the Jmeter section

Answer (score 0):

[HTTP Status 400](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400) means "bad request", one of your request parameters is not correct, like URL or request data or [request headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers), cross check them with browser/postman

If you're able to successfully execute the request using Postman you can just record the request from Postman using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)

1. Start JMeter proxy server
2. Configure Postman to use JMeter as the [proxy](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/capturing-request-data/proxy/)
3. Run your request in Postman
4. JMeter will capture the request and generate appropriate HTTP Request sampler and HTTP Header Manager

More information: [How to Convert Your Postman API Tests to JMeter for Scaling](https://www.blazemeter.com/how-to-convert-your-postman-api-tests-to-jmeter-for-scaling)